# Elasticsearch scroll API not returning all my hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't seem to retrieve all my hits using the scroll API. Right now, only 10 are returned.

`http://host:port/_search?scroll=1m`

returns

```
{
  "_scroll_id": "scroll_id"
  ...
  ...
  "hits": {
    "hits": [{10 hits in there}]
  }
}
```

I take the `_scroll_id` value and I perform this POST next

```
http://host:port/_search/scroll -d {
    "scroll": "1m",
    "scroll_id": "scroll_id"
}
```

It seems like I get the same response in return when I want all my hits to be returned instead

Comment: is this your initial query, `http://host:port/_search?scroll=1m`? are you specifying index and type?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 i didn't specify the index and type. I just tried it with the index and type and got the same results

Comment: You need to specify index and type **only** during initial request and subsequent requests should not contain index and type. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) on that.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 still getting the same results. I am using postman fro everything. Initial post: https://postimg.org/image/czr5u7lt5/  second post: https://postimg.org/image/tnt1o8gs3/

Comment: You might be confused about **scroll_id**, you can get same scroll_id over multiple requests, are you sure results are different? I tried on ES 2.3 and it is working fine, which version of ES you are using?